# How to get this javascript promise to work

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Ive been trying to find the simplest JavaScript promise(without libraries) so i can get it into my thick skull. Thought i was getting the concept, but seem to be unable to work it. Can anyone fix this?

```
function fetch(message){
     return message;
 }
var promise = fetch('beep')
promise.then(function(dMessage){
    console.log(dMessage);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error('error-', err);
})
```

ERROR Message:**promise.then is not a function**

Am also a little confused about when i can use this? NodeJs will be able to use this without extra libraries right? for client side i should get ES6-promise?

**Solution underneath with thanks to Daniel B**

```
function fetch(message){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(message);
    });
}
fetch('word').then(function(dMess){
    console.log(dMess);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error('error-', err);
})
```

Comment: Basically this translates to `'beep'.then( ... )` and you're not using the `Promise` class at all.

Comment: Don't define `function fetch(message){ ` it's already defined for you by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the native `fetch` function. Simply remove your function and it will work.

If you want to define your own `fetch` function, it has to return a promise, as below.

```
function fetch(message){
    return Promise.resolve(message);
}
```

Comment: Oh, Benjamin beat be to it. Might perhaps be helpful anyway.

Comment: yeeeaaay! My Hero, Thanks!! i was allmost there actually , but i was trying to return the message rather than resolving it.

Comment: Thanks, so both ways work, is there anything that makes these two Promises run differently that can't be perceived right away? Any preferred method of the 2?

Comment: You just should `return Promise.resolve(message);`. No need to call `then`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the other answer is correct. Although it's correct in 'fetch' is a method native to browsers (not javascript which the user implied) it is not the reason why your promise doesn't work, and doesn't explain what you're not understanding about promises.

The first 'promise' in a chain always has to be a promise constructor/instance. You can create these in many ways, but if you have only a simple value like a string, you must wrap it in Promise.resolve(string). Afterwords, and other promises in the chain won't need this functionality as they are all wrapped in the top level promise of the chain. At least this is how most implementations like Q/Bluebird/ES6 Native promises will work.

Comment: wouldn't it be safer just to resolve them all, the way i see it, ill be writing a whole bunch of promises that all perform a certain kind of task which ill call upon and require over and over again and not always in exactly the same order.

Comment: I don't see how my answer is incorrect since it clearly wraps the `string` value in a promise. Your answer stating that the reason the OP's code is failing for some other reason is clearly wrong though. His `promise` simply isn't a promise. Also, the question doesn't ask anything further than how to get it working. There tons of resources on the internet if one wants to read up on promises in general.

Comment: Fighto! Just kidding, Dont Fighto! thanks for answering my questions, I have a lesson with a javascript guru tomorrow, so i'll ask him then.